# How can I efficiently updates a thousands of records using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How to updates in fastest way all record table_id from table B depends on link of both table using old_id. I have multiple records on both table and every time I update table 2 it takes time to update all table_id from table B. Any suggestion on how to speed up updates of records.

Here are my query that takes time on updates:  All of 3 query I already tested but it gives very slow updates. Any suggestion please:

```
Query 1:
 UPDATE Table_B dest 
 SET table_id = (SELECT id FROM Table_A WHERE old_id = dest.old_id ) 
 WHERE table_id = 0;

Query 2:
 UPDATE Table_B dest
 INNER JOIN Table_A src  ON dest.old_id = src .old_id
 SET dest.table_id = src .id 
 WHERE dest.table_id = 0;

Query 3:
 UPDATE Table_B dest, Table_A src 
 SET dest.table_id = src.id
 WHERE dest.old_id = src.old_id AND dest.table_id = 0;

Table_A
id | old_id | fullname
 1    2131     Name 1
 2    2132     Name 2
 3    2133     Name 3
 4    2134     Name 4
 ..................... and so on (8000 records)


Table_B
id | table_id | old_id | work
 1     0         2131     Work 1
 2     0         2131     Work 2
 3     0         2131     Work 3
 4     0         2132     Work 1
 5     0         2132     Work 2
 6     0         2132     Work 3
 7     0         2133     Work 1
 8     0         2134     Work 1
 ..................... and so on (55000 records)
```

Comment: do you have indexes defined on dest.table_id, dest.old_id and src.old_id? If not, indexing these fields would make the queris faster.

Comment: You probably need to index TableA.old_id. Indexing the other id fields probably won't help much in these queries

Comment: ok thanks for help. Index really works. Great help bro.